# How to store the check box values instantly without page submit to another Item oracle

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I want to get the checkbox values assigned instantly to an item as ":" separated.

When i select checkbox it should assign the value into an item instantly without submitting the page.

Below Example taken from Google, but i want as the same shown in image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you define the checkboxes like this in the report SQL:

```
apex_item.checkbox2(1,null,'class="sel-cbx" data-value="'||empno||'"',empno) as sel
```

Then a dynamic action on change of jQuery selector 'sel-cbx' can execute this Javascript to maintain the list in the item:

```
let a = [];
$('.sel-cbx:checked').each(function() {
    a.push($(this).attr('data-value'))
});
$s('P10_EMPNO_LIST',a.join(':'));
```

(I'm sure there's a neater way to write the Javascript, but it works.)